# Thread networking causing null pointer exceptions

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception

As I am learning networking in the android area, I have encountered a problem that is only present on device testing (not emulator testing).

Ran the app on the device and I got a network error, so I created a new thread for the network task like so (using a class to download and return a JSON object).

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static JSONArray jArray = null;
    static String json = "";
    // constructor
            public JSONParser() {
        }
    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {
        // Making HTTP request
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    // defaultHttpClient
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                            is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line);
                    }
                    is.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }
                // return JSON String

            }
        }).start();

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Now, back in my main code I instantiate the object like so:

```
JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
JSONObject jArray = j.getJSONFromUrl(url); // url being a predefined variable
```

The problem here now is `jArray` is null since making it work on a different thread - I am wondering at the moment if the thread is (due to network connection) not loading the data before execution of the code.

Am I right in thinking this is the problem or is there a possibility of another issue somewhere?

**I will paste here the full code and also the stack trace:**

Where `GlobalSettings.java` is called from `FragmentTab3.java`:

```
try{
        newsText = globalSettings.getNews();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`GlobalSettings.java`

```
public String getNews()
    {
        // will be a string with news content
        String valueToReturn = null;

        try{
            JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jArray = j.getJSONFromUrl(url);

            //Log.i("log_tag_one", jArray.toString());

            int jLen = jArray.length();
            String jLenStr = Integer.toString(jLen);

            //Log.i("log_tag_two", jLenStr);

            String jsonvalues = null;


            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray;
                jsonvalues = json_data.getString("FeaturedNews");
                // .. get all value here
                //Log.i("DARE", jsonvalues);
            }

            // turn string -> array jsonvalues
            String[] jsonForIteration = jsonvalues.split(",");
            //JSONObject jValues = jsonvalues;

            // Position 4 is always going to be the news text
            //Log.i("LOG FROM ENUMERATION ==>>", jsonForIteration[4]);

            valueToReturn = jsonForIteration[4];

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error getJSONfromURL " + ex.toString());
        }

        return valueToReturn;
    }

    public String[][] getScrollingItems() {

        // will be a object with images
        String[][] data = new String[6][6];

        try {
            JSONParser j = new JSONParser();
            JSONObject jArray = j.getJSONFromUrl(urlForImages);

            // define variables for the switch below which at the moment produces the
            // individual objects for display

            JSONArray anotherJson = null;
            JSONObject object1;

            try {
                anotherJson = jArray.getJSONArray("FeaturedLinks");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < anotherJson.length(); i++) {

                object1 = anotherJson.getJSONObject(i);

                data[i][0] = object1.getString("Image");
                data[i][1] = object1.getString("Link");

            }

            // end initial try
            // TOO MANY DAMN TRYS! :(
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    } // end method
```

**Stack Trace**

```
09-22 15:23:40.102    6500-6519/packageName.com.packageNameEdited E/Version﹕ 231, Applause client library for Android v2.3.1
09-22 15:23:40.112    6500-6519/packageName.com.packageNameEdited E/Version﹕ 1, 0.3.3
09-22 15:23:40.192    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited E/log_tag﹕ Error getJSONfromURL java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 15:23:40.192    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 15:23:40.192    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.FragmentTab3.onCreateView(FragmentTab3.java:46)
09-22 15:23:40.192    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
09-22 15:23:40.192    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5126)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
09-22 15:23:40.202    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.GlobalSettings.getScrollingItems(GlobalSettings.java:81)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.FragmentTab3.onCreateView(FragmentTab3.java:65)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5126)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.GlobalSettings.getScrollingItems(GlobalSettings.java:86)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.FragmentTab3.onCreateView(FragmentTab3.java:65)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5126)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
09-22 15:23:40.222    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40d44ae0)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited E/ApplauseUncaughtExceptionHandler﹕ Applause intercepted uncaught exception: java.lang.RuntimeException -> Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageName.com.packageNameEdited/packageName.com.packageNameEdited.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageName.com.packageNameEdited/packageName.com.packageNameEdited.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.232    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.FragmentTab3.onCreateView(FragmentTab3.java:66)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5126)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ ... 11 more
09-22 15:23:40.242    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited I/ApplauseClient﹕ Reporting crash to Applause.
09-22 15:23:40.252    6500-6500/packageName.com.packageNameEdited E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{packageName.com.packageNameEdited/packageName.com.packageNameEdited.MyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2186)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
            at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
            at android.util.Log.i(Log.java:159)
            at packageName.com.packageNameEdited.FragmentTab3.onCreateView(FragmentTab3.java:66)
            at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
            at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5126)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:145)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1238)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5099)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:803)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:570)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Edit 1: onCreateView for `FragmentTab3.java`**:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabhome, container, false);


        // get the news for main text
        GlobalSettings globalSettings = new GlobalSettings();

        String newsText = "?";

        try{
            newsText = globalSettings.getNews().replace("\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        TextView newsTextArea = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.newsTextView);

        newsTextArea.setSingleLine(false);
        newsTextArea.setMinLines(2);

        String[][] imageArray = globalSettings.getScrollingItems();
        Log.i("Image data at: --> ", imageArray[2][1]);

        newsTextArea.setText(newsText);


        // add images and links(?)

        // image one
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.insideScroll);
            HorizontalScrollView sv = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.latestScroller);
            final ImageViewWithURL iv = new ImageViewWithURL(view.getContext());

            try {
                // set the URL of the image
                iv.setURL(imageArray[i][1]);
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(imageArray[i][0]).openStream());
                iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

                iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        //Log.i("Debug inside:", iv.getURL());
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(iv.getURL()));
                        startActivity(browserIntent);
                    }
                });

            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            lv.addView(iv);
        } // end for

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: try using async tasks instead of threads, imho easier for beginning threadeds in android and there are tons of examples out there how to use them and wait for results (e.g. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html starts with an example)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I right in thinking this is the problem or is there a possibility of another issue somewhere?

I think you are completely wrong.

According to the stacktrace, the NPE is **caused by your logging**.  Read the exception message!!!

```
  09-22 15:23:40.232 .../packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ 
      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
  09-22 15:23:40.242 .../packageName.com.packageNameEdited W/System.err﹕ 
          at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
```

The offending logger call is in a method called `onCreateView` ... which you haven't shown us.

---

**UPDATE**

At @Mark W's prompting, I came back to this Question, and ... yes ... he is correct.  Once you get past the immediate cause of the NPE, the fundamental cause of your problem is in `getJSONFromUrl`.

The way the code is written at the moment, it is pretty much inevitable that `getJSONFromUrl` will return `null`.  What it does is to create and start a thread that is going to fetch and parse some JSON from a remote site.  But instead of waiting for the thread to complete, the `getJSONFromUrl` method is going to immediately return the value in `jObj`.  But that is going to be `null` at that point in time.

Obviously, if `getJSONFromUrl` is going to return the JSON, it *has to wait* for the thread to complete.  But that defeats the (true) purpose of doing the fetch on a separate thread ... because waiting will block the event listener thread, making your app  non-responsive while the JSON is being fetched.

There are other problems with the implementation of `getJSONFromUrl` as well:

- `JSONParser` declares some `static` variables that are used to communicate between the two threads.  But suppose that the main (event listener) thread calls `getJSONFromUrl` two times in rapid succession.  Then you are likely to have two threads fetching JSON and assigning it to *the same* `jObj` variable.  That is clearly wrong.
- Assuming that you get the variable sorted out, you still have the problem that two threads that communicate via a shared variable need to be properly synchronized ... or else you are liable to get memory anomalies.

All in all, there are lots of problems at lots of levels with your multi-threading.  I'd recommend that follow @Christian W's advice in the comment above:

- On Android, it is better to use AsyncTasks rather than threads.  They are easier to use.
- If you want to persist with using threads, you need to read up on how to do multi-threading properly in Java.  Try the Oracle Java Tutorial.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment here - I am still learning all this! I have edited my OP to include the `onCreateView` method from `FragmentTab3.java`

Comment: Okay so I have just commented out this line `Log.i("Image data at: --> ", imageArray[2][1]);` and the app runs without crashing. However, the data that should be downloaded isn't anywhere, it is null. I have stepped through it via breakpoint and the variables that are supposed to receive the data are set to `null` (eg variable: `jArray` remains null).

Comment: While technically right Stephen, it would seem Josh does not understand the nature of threading well, as he only sets the JSON objects via his Runnable. Then he instantly returns the reference to a null. That null propagates through the rest of his code, which is why nothing happens as he expects. The NPE was a only a symptom. No -1 though, cuz you make him read his stack trace.